# Any distinctions between "amenable" and "receptive"?

Tags: meaning, difference

> amenable
>
> Definition: ready or willing to answer, act, agree, or yield; open to influence, persuasion, or advice; agreeable; submissive; tractable tractable:
>
> an amenable child
>
> The children are generally amenable to our wishes (usually goes with "to")
>
> a government that is not amenable to change [=a government that resists change]

> receptive:
>
> Definition: willing to listen to or accept ideas, suggestions, etc.
>
> Examples: I was happy to be speaking before such a receptive audience.
>
> He was receptive to the idea of going back to school.

Both terms pretty much express the same meaning of willing to agree or accept new suggestions or ideas.

Comment: One is "willing to answer act agree or yield" and the other is "willing to listen, accept ideas"  So they are similar, but different.  "act" doesn't mean the same as "listen".  Is there some specific context you had in mind?

Comment: Duplicate: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/316472/what-is-the-difference-between-receptive-and-amenable

Answer (score 1):

Some of the difference between these words is in how they are used.

***Amenable*** is typically used in situations where a person is willing to agree to a specific deal or task; it is rarely used to describe a person who agrees to anything and everything.  "He is amenable to sell his business" does not mean that he is of a personality to agree to anything and everything.  It is specifically about his *receptiveness* to a *specific idea*.

Note that I find the specific example sentences given in your dictionary to be technically acceptable, but misleading as to how the word is typically used.  You *can* use amenable to refer to general disposition, but even here you have to specify the domain of what they are amenable to.  The child is amenable *to our wishes*.  The government is not amenable *to change*.  Amenable is almost always used with the word "to".  You are amenable "to" something, and usage suggests that in general, the more specific you are, the better.

Citation: [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=amenable%20to%2Camenable%20-to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Camenable%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camenable%20-%20to%3B%2Cc0).  "amenable to" is commonly used.  Amenable without "to" is almost never used.

In contrast, ***receptive*** is a more general state.  You can be receptive *to* something specifically, but unlike amenable, you don't have to be.  You can simply be receptive.  Note the example: they are a receptive audience.  The sentence didn't have to say that the audience was receptive *to me*.  It could have, but it is by no means necessary to do so.

The grammar of the two words can also be different in usage.  Both words are adjectives, but **amenable** is rarely used in the {adjective} {noun} structure.  This is one reason I dislike the example sentences for amenable.  "He is an amenable child" is correct, but doesn't follow typical usage.  "The child is amenable (to do something...)" is far, FAR more common.  My intuitive feeling for **receptive** is that it is used both ways equally: "The audience is receptive" and "this is a receptive audience are roughly equal in usage.

Citations: [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=receptive%20_NOUN_%2Creceptive%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creceptive%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creceptive%20to%3B%2Cc0).  A "receptive {NOUN}" and "receptive to" are about equally used.
[Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=amenable%20_NOUN_%2Camenable%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Camenable%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camenable%20to%3B%2Cc0) An "amenable {NOUN}" is very rare, while "amenable to" is common.

Comment: What a nicely crafted answer.